# Python code seems to be getting executed out of order

Tags: python, debugging

At work I have a programming language encoded in a database record. I'm trying to write a print function in python to display what the record contains.

This is the code I'm having trouble with:

```
    # Un-indent the block if necessary.
    if func_option[row.FRML_FUNC_OPTN] in ['Endif', 'Else']:
        self.indent = self.indent - 1

    # if this is a new line, indent it.
    if len(self.formulatext) <> 0 and self.formulatext[len(self.formulatext) - 1] == '\n':
        for i in range(1,self.indent):
            rowtext = '    ' + rowtext

    # increase indent for 'then', 'else'
    if func_option[row.FRML_FUNC_OPTN] in ['Then', 'Else']:
        self.indent = self.indent + 1
```

When row.FRML____FUNC____OPTN equals 'Else', I expect it to first un-indent, then indent again, so that the 'else' is printed at a lower level of indentation, then the rest of the code is within. Instead this is the type of indentation I get:

```
IfThen
        IfThen
            Else
        EndifComment
        IfThen
        Endif
        IfThen
            Else
        Endif
    Else
Endif
```

As you can see the 'Else' is still indented higher than the If / Endif. Any idea why this could be happening?

I did try sprinkling the code with debug statements the result of which is:

```
row:     Else
row.FRML_FUNC_OPTN is : Elsedecrementing indent
row.FRML_FUNC_OPTN is : Elseincrementing indent
```

which means that the indent altering if's are indeed being entered...

Comment: Put some logging in your code to trace it. For instance, are you sure func_option is 'Else'? Maybe it's 'else', or some other permutation? You might not be hitting the unindent/indent code at all.

Comment: I did actually sprinkle the code with debug statements.

row:     Else
row.FRML_FUNC_OPTN is : Elsedecrementing indent
row.FRML_FUNC_OPTN is : Elseincrementing indent

Comment: Could rowtext already contain spaces at the start?

Comment: I did think about that possibility... I'm absolutely sure that it doesnt :( . rowtext is just blank at the start of this code

Comment: Then you probably have spaces in whatever you're prepending it to.

Comment: debugging is completely irrelevant here, Alterlife.

Comment: voting to close, this is not the way to ask questions.

Comment: As it turns out, the formula in the table that I'm reading from has an additional row with just a 'Then' without an 'If'. I have code to eliminate Thens without 'If's for the print elsewhere, in my function but I didn't eliminate the 'if'. Thanks for your help chrispy. Much appreciated :) .

Comment: And I would suggest you vote to delete this question, Alterlife.

Comment: Agree, I can't see this being useful to anyone else.

Comment: I can't delete it. 
Stackoverflow says: Sorry, this question cannot be deleted: too many existing answers, or upvoted/accepted answers
(click on this box to dismiss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your debug log:

```
row:     Else
row.FRML_FUNC_OPTN is : Elsedecrementing indent
row.FRML_FUNC_OPTN is : Elseincrementing indent
```

I suspect you already have indentation before "Else" when you enter the code fragment supplied.

Try adding:

```
rowtext = rowtext.strip()
```

just before the first if

Or if rowtext is blank, and you're adding it to something else later on, try calling strip on *that*.

Comment: As it turns out, the formula in the table that I'm reading from has an additional row with just a 'Then' without an 'If'. I have code to eliminate Thens without 'If's for the print elsewhere, in my function but I didn't eliminate the 'if'. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated :) .

Answer (score 2):

Just because it is a "script language" doesn't mean you have to live without a full debugger with breakpoints !

- Install eric3
- Load your code
- Press "debug" ;)

Also, you seem new to Python, so here are a few hints :

- you can multiply strings, much faster than a loop
- read how array access works, use [-1] for last element
- read on string methods, use .endswith()
- use tuples for static unmutable data, faster

> 

```
# Un-indent the block if necessary.
op = func_option[row.FRML_FUNC_OPTN]
if op in ('Endif', 'Else'):
    self.indent -= 1

# if this is a new line, indent it.
if self.formulatext.endswith( '\n' ):
    rowtext = ("\t" * indent) + rowtext

# increase indent for 'then', 'else'
if op in ('Then', 'Else'):
    self.indent += 1
```